# Видео из ютуб не показывает на полный экран в webview?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, создал приложение для сайта,на сайте есть видео из ютуба видео воспроизводится но не переходит на полный экран. в WebView такую функцию к сожаление надо настраивать вручную, помогите пожалуйста? спасибо. Вот решения которые нашел но немогу выполнить: https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/262167/
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

```
MAIN ACTIVITY.JAVA
package com.kino_films.uzbekkino;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.loadUrl("http://kino-films.com");
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
}

Manifest

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kino_films.uzbekkino">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

active main

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kino_films.uzbekkino.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Буду очень благодарен если поможете. С уважением

Comment: когда вы в вебвью нажимаете "на весь экран", то видео не на весь экран показывается. Я правильно понял? Покажите, как оно показывается.

Comment: @metalurgus нет, при нажатии "на весь экран" ничего не происходит. Так как в коде нет обработки калбэков веб вью на открытие во весь экран.

Comment: @user224437 вы бы подробнее описали почему не можете использовать решения ссылки на которые привели. В статье на хабре вроде всё вполне доходчиво описано.

Answer (score 1):

"во весь экран" видео придется показывать вручную. Делается это при помощи `WebChromeClient`:

```
private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    //LayoutParams для режима FullScreen
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        // Если уже есть View для fullscreen, то убираем его
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }
        //прячем обычный View (не fullscreen). Показано для примера, отредактироовать в зависимости от своей структуры
        mContentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //создаем контейнер для fullscreen View
        mCustomViewContainer = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
        mCustomViewContainer.setLayoutParams(layoutParameters);
        mCustomViewContainer.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParameters);
        mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
        mCustomView = view;
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //заменяем текущий ContentView
        setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        if (mCustomView == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            // прячем Fullscreen View
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // убираем его из контейнера 
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            // показываем обычный View  
            mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setContentView(mContentView);
        }
    }
}
```

Это пример для использования внутри `Activity`. Можно сделать проще, например добавляя и удаляя `View` поверх текущего `View` внутри методов `onShowCustomView` и `onHideCustomView`